# Verificação de extensão do arquivo e mudar o seu diretório

Tags: python

Estou com problema em um script python que verifica se existem arquivos com alguma extensão específica no diretório e move todo o diretório para um outro destino

Isto é um teste para automatizar o processo de mover um diretório para outro lugar dependendo de sua extensão, mas eu só consigo realizar isso se todos os arquivos possuírem a mesma extensão, caso contrário, mesmo que exista somente um arquivo com a extensão desejada ele não realiza a mudança de diretório.

Conteúdo do diretório 'testar_mover_diretorio':

arquivo_texto.txt

arquivo_python.py

```
import os, shutil


def verificar_dir(diretorio, extensao, destino):
    if (os.path.exists(diretorio) == True):
        for pasta, subpastas, arquivos in os.walk(diretorio):
            for arquivo in arquivos:
                extensao_arquivo = arquivo.endswith(extensao)
                if (extensao_arquivo == True):
                    result = ('Existem arquivos com a extensão {} na pasta').format(extensao)
                    if (os.path.exists(destino) == True):
                        shutil.move(diretorio, destino)
                    else:
                        result = 'O diretório de destino não existe'
                else:
                    result = ('Não existem arquivos com a extensão {} na pasta').format(extensao)
        return print(result)

    else:
        print('Este diretório não existe')

diretorio = input('Qual é o diretório que você deseja verificar? ')
extensao = input('Qual é a extensão que você procura? ')
destino = input('Qual será o destino deste diretório? ')
print('')

verificar_dir(diretorio, extensao, destino)
```

Exemplo: Eu tenho uma pasta 'teste_mover_diretorio' na área de trabalho com arquivos '.txt' e '.py' e quero mover ela para o diretorio 'Projetos', mas o script não realiza a mudança mesmo havendo um arquivo '.py' dentro da pasta.

Comment: esse script tem alguns problemas, mas o código como está vai fazer a udança quando achar o _primeiro_ arquivo com a extensão desejada. (eu nem sei se ele não quebra imediatamente após isso). Definitivamente esse código acima não vai fazer a ação "somente se todos os arquivos tiverem a extensão desejada". Ou o código está diferente do que você roda aí, ou a pergunta não está clara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para versões iguais ou superiores a 3.4 da linguagem utilize o pacote [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) para gerenciar diretórios e arquivos. A API dele é mais direta e simples que a fornecida pelo pacote `os`.

1. Para abrir um diretório, use `foo = pathlib.Path('./foo')`;
2. Para buscar arquivos com determinada extensão, use `foo.glob('*.py')`;
3. Se retornar pelo menos um arquivo, renomeie o diretório;

Em código ficaria algo como:

```
from pathlib import Path

foo = Path('foo')

for _ in foo.glob('*.py'):
    foo.rename('bar')
    break
else:
    print('Nenhum arquivo .py encontrado')
```

Assim, se você possuir o diretório:

```
/foo
    main.py
```

Ao rodar o programa terá

```
/bar
    main.py
```

Mas cuidado com as condições de corrida se houverem múltiplos processos manipulando o mesmo diretório de forma paralela.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Não conhecia esta API, pesquisarei mais sobre ela e suas funcionalidades. O código fica bem mais amigável e simples